# "Server too busy" after moving to fcgid

Tags: apache-2.2, centos6, varnish, mod-fcgid

I was previously using mod_fastcgi and had issues [as described here](https://serverfault.com/questions/575293/oom-issues-with-fastcgi-fastcgiserver-config-getting-ignored) with configurations getting ignored. After moving to mod_fcgid, I've seen a whole new issue which is causing issues for all sites hosted on the server.

At random intervals throughout the day, the server outputs a "Server too busy" message to requests and I'm not sure what is outputting it- fcgid, apache2 or varnish. Under what circumstances would this message usually show and what are my options to prevent it from happening again?

Thanks

Comment: What does the _rest_ of the message say?

Comment: That's literately it, with a 503 code!

Comment: Didn't you check the error log?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Checking out varnish and apache2 showed that they both returned 200 OK codes. The issue was actually load balancer on our hosting providers network intercepting responses.

Answer (score 0):

Give Apache a bigger RAM allowance! Apache 2.2 defaults to a very small amount so you would probably want to increase it (Unless you have a terrible PC)!